# Round Corners in RadialBar Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

i want to add round corners to **radial bar** using highcharts is there a way i can do it?

I was able to add round corners to simple column chart using 'borderRadius'. Here is an example

https://jsfiddle.net/agbvnm91/1/.

```
column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0.01,
            pointWidth: 10,
            borderRadius: 10
        }
```

But it's not working for radial bar. Here is example of what I tried https://jsfiddle.net/agbvnm91/1/.

Comment: At the moment there is no borderRadius option implemented for radial bars. The reason for that is the circular nature of points (they aren't rects just as non-circular columns). Such functionality for paths must be implemented the similar way as it is implemented for solidgauges (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.solidgauge.rounded).

Comment: can i add dataLabels to solidguage like this https://imgur.com/a/h46wmjt